# How to check if the string has consequitive special characters more than 2 in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to check the string whether it have the special characters more than 2 times.
The String I obtained are from List using the following code:

```
List <String> lst;
for(String str: lst)
{
System.out.println(str);
}
```

Say Input example:

```
This is sample example.
########################
This will help you for sure
"my friend" do not ask to delay more.
$$200 not much
sssssss
better to go home.
```

I want to have the output something like this:

```
This is sample example.
This will help you for sure
"my friend" do not ask to delay more.
$$200 not much
better to go home.
```

How I can achieve this output using JAVA? Kindly suggest a way.

Comment: So the example you gave, is it one single string ( with '\n' ) or they are different inputs?

Comment: @AnandUndavia these are different string. LIne by line.

Comment: @AnandUndavia you can see my edited question once.

Comment: Okay so want to check if the string has two consecutive special characters, and if string has more than 2 consecutive special characters, you want to remove that string from the list ?

Comment: Isn't $(USD) a special character??.

Comment: Yes something like that. I want to display on the right and proper strings from the list. But want to check one by one.

Comment: Regex: `s.replaceAll("(.)\\1{2,}", "");`

Comment: why `sssssss` are special characters?

Comment: @SrikanthA `$` is indeed special character. But the fact is my string can have 2 special symbol or character  not more than that

Comment: Try this `string.replaceAll("^.*[._\'!#$%&*+\\\\/=?{|}~`\\^-]{2}.*$", "");`

Comment: @JafferWilson why sssssss is removed from output?

Comment: @SrikanthA I already have cleared that point my friend. 2 special character allowed. Say like english syntax you may consider. I can write please or by typo pleasse. This may happen. but allowed.

Comment: @Jerry06 Yes you are right. But is a repeated more than 2, so I consider it as special one.

Comment: @SrikanthA I like the registry expression giving by Krishnanunni. It worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:
`string.replaceAll("^.*[._\'!#$%&*+\\\\/=?{|}~\\^-]{2}.*$", "");`

Comment: An explanation of the expression would most likely be helpful to the OP as well.

Comment: Your comment regex worked for me like charm... :) Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

make a char array and search through each to see if 3 special characters appear, if so remove (or in my case below, do not copy that String to the newList that will be used for printing.  I did not remove the ssssssss string because it is not special characters, but you could do that too if you made an additional if and checked if 3 consecutive chars had the same value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       List <String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
       List <String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
       lst.add("This is sample example.");
       lst.add("########################");
       lst.add("This will help you for sure");
       lst.add("\"my friend\" do not ask to delay more.");
       lst.add("$$200 not much");
       lst.add("sssssss");
       lst.add("better to go home.");

       for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
           boolean keep = true;
           char[] c = lst.get(i).toCharArray();
           for(int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) { 

//the following line can be edited based on what you consider special characters
```

//but this will allow for all numbers and letters

```
               if(j+2 < c.length && (c[j] < 48 || c[j] > 122 ||(c[j] > 57 && c[j] < 65))) {
                   if(c[j+1] < 65 || c[j+1] > 122 ||(c[j] > 57 && c[j] < 65)) {
                       if(c[j+2] < 65 || c[j+2] > 122 ||(c[j] > 57 && c[j] < 65)) {
                           keep = false;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           if(keep) {
               newList.add(lst.get(i));
           }
       }

       for(String str: newList)
    {
    System.out.println(str);
    }
    }
```

Comment: This could be nicer if you called another method and used recursion I'm sure than using a triple if statement.  That is just the first thing that occurred to me.

Comment: why negative vote?  It runs for me, am i misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Please read my question once again. And I have not downvoted you. your answer is not what is satisfying my question. Hence, you might have got the downvote.